# Probability of getting HHT vs. HTT but using Markov Chains?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, recursive-algorithms, geometric-series

So I conduct interviews for candidates sometimes, and one of my go to questions is [this classic question](https://dicedcoins.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/flip-hhh-before-htt/):

> If you keep rolling a fair coin, what is the probability that you will get HHT before HTT (H = heads, T = tails)?

Now it is easily solved by using conditional probabilities by simply laying out the set of equations for each state. So by solving for probability of winning $P(W)$:

$$ P(W) = \frac{1}{2} P(W|H) + \frac{1}{2} P(W|T)$$

$$ P(W|H) = \frac{1}{2} P(W|HH) + \frac{1}{2} P(W|HT)$$

$$ P(W|T) = P(W) $$

and so on. The answer is known $P(W)=\frac{2}{3}$ and this question has been answered online a lot.

---

However, today a candidate had an approach i hadn't seen before. They tried to basically solve it all in one go, by using a Markov Chain and multiplying the probabilities of each transition together. They then "normalized both outcomes". Visually, here's what that looks like:

[image]

And then saying that to calculate probability of winning "unnormalized", which I will denote with a hat:

$$ P(\hat{W}) = P(\texttt{node_0 to node_1})*P(\texttt{node_1 to node_2})*P(\texttt{node_2 to node_3})$$

So each transition is 1/2, but $P(\texttt{node_2 to node_3})= 1-P(\texttt{node_2 to node_2})$, so it's $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$ because there's a cycle that messes things up i guess, so it's solved by "summing up the contributions of that cycle, which is a geometric series"

So final probability is:

$$ P(\hat{W}) = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{1-1/2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

By the same logic for $P(\hat{L})$:

$$ P(\hat{L}) = P(\texttt{node_0 to node_1})*P(\texttt{node_1 to node_4})*P(\texttt{node_4 to node_5})$$

Because "there's a cycle between nodes 1 and 4, $P(\texttt{node_1 to node_4}) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$". This follows from their earlier approach with $P(\texttt{node_2 to node_3})$ I guess? So:

$$P(\texttt{node_1 to node_4})= 1-P(\texttt{node_4 to node_4})= \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$

Putting this all together:

$$ P(\hat{L}) = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Then to normalize, you do:

$$P(W) = \frac{P(\hat{W})}{P(\hat{W}) + P(\hat{L})}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{ \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{6}{10}$$.

---

- All "quoted phrases" are directly from the candidate, so I don't quite understand them either

Uhm, at this point I was so lost and had to move on. Any suggestions on what the candidate was going for? I tried so much to help but they were too deep into this solution that I couldn't understand what they were going for. I messed around with their solution for a while after, and if we set $P(\hat{L})=\frac{1}{4}$ it works. But I still don't understand the flaw in their logic there.

Would love any feedback on how to actually solve it this way, and any pointers as to what this type of solution is called, because I had a hard time looking up this particular method of solving it, and I'd like to be a better interviewer and learn more while doing it.

Comment: Somewhat *off-topic*:I am unfamiliar with Markov chains, but I can offer independent intuition why HHT is more likely to precede HTT, even though, the two sequences are (in general) equally likely.  It is because of how likely HHT is to be distributed *with* HTT.  A disproprotionate amount of the time, HTT will **immediately** follow HHT, while the reverse placement is impossible.

Comment: Can't follow this at all.  What does it mean to say that the probability of going from node $2$ to node $3$ is $\frac 1{1-\frac 12}=2$?  Similarly, $\frac 1{1-\frac 14}$ is simply not a probability.

Comment: There is also a missing self-loop at node 6.

Comment: @lulu I wish I could help with that, i don't get it either. It's something related to their being an infinite component to going from node 2 to node 3 where you could go HHT or HHHT or HHHHT, etc. Essentially that this is a geometric series, so they solved for 1-($\Sigma$P(HHT)+P(HHHT)+P(HHHHT).....) to account for all possible recursions?

Comment: @angryavian that cancels out with both unnormalized scenarios, because $P(W)=P(W|H)$

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees I think properly doing that geometric series would just give you the fact that if you are in state 2, you will eventually reach state 3 with probability 1.

Comment: @angryavian ok so $P(\hat{W})=1/2*1/2*1=1/4$? still adds up to $P(W)=3/7$ I guess..

Comment: At a guess, they are computing expected values of some sort (those fractions look like the values of infinite Geometric Series).  But how you pass from those (conditional, I guess) expected values to probabilities eludes me.

Comment: States $0$ and $6$ are unnecessary, since we only care about sequences that start with heads.

Comment: @saulspatz, correct, don't want to update the image now though in case people are already answering

Comment: It seems to me that the candidate had a reasonable idea in using Markov chains, but didn't remember how to compute the probabilities of absorption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

States 3 and 5 are the absorbing states of the Markov chain. The question is what is the probability of ending up in each state.

There are some simplifications we can make.

- With probability 1, we will reach state 1. (Equivalently, the probability of never seeing a heads is zero.)
- If we are in state 2, we will eventually reach state 3 with probability 1.

So, we can consider the simplified problem of starting in state 1, and asking about the probability of reaching state 2 before state 5.

The only way to reach state 2 from state 1 is to do the loop between states 1 and 4 a number of times, and then going to state 2. The sum of the probabilities of these outcomes is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \right)^k \frac{1}{2}
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: Oh, this seems like it's the solution they were trying to go for. One followup, does the whole normalization aspect of their answer still fit in here? Not quite sure what they meant by that